# #pragma omp parallel for reduces speed instead of increasing - in Lattic Boltzman

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am new to OpenMP and I am trying to parallelize this loop:

```
int ii,jj,kk;                 /* generic counters */
const double c_sq = 1.0/3.0;  /* square of speed of sound */
const double w0 = 4.0/9.0;    /* weighting factor */
const double w1 = 1.0/9.0;    /* weighting factor */
const double w2 = 1.0/36.0;   /* weighting factor */
double u_x,u_y;               /* av. velocities in x and y directions */
double u[NSPEEDS];            /* directional velocities */
double d_equ[NSPEEDS];        /* equilibrium densities */
double u_sq;                  /* squared velocity */
double local_density;         /* sum of densities in a particular cell */

/* loop over the cells in the grid
** NB the collision step is called after
** the propagate step and so values of interest
** are in the scratch-space grid */
//#pragma omp parallel for private (ii, jj, kk, d_equ) shared (cells, tmp_cells)
for(ii=0;ii<params.ny;ii++) {
 for(jj=0;jj<params.nx;jj++) {
  /* don't consider occupied cells */
  if(!obstacles[ii*params.nx + jj]) {
    /* compute local density total */
    local_density = 0.0;
    for(kk=0;kk<NSPEEDS;kk++) {
      local_density += tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[kk];
    }
    /* compute x velocity component */
    u_x = (tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[1] +
           tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[5] +
           tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[8]
           - (tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[3] +
              tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[6] +
              tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[7]))
      / local_density;
    u_y = (tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[2] +
           tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[5] +
           tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[6]
           - (tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[4] +
              tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[7] +
              tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[8]))
      / local_density;
    /* velocity squared */
    u_sq = u_x * u_x + u_y * u_y;
    /* directional velocity components */
    u[1] =   u_x;        /* east */
    u[2] =         u_y;  /* north */
    u[3] = - u_x;        /* west */
    u[4] =       - u_y;  /* south */
    u[5] =   u_x + u_y;  /* north-east */
    u[6] = - u_x + u_y;  /* north-west */
    u[7] = - u_x - u_y;  /* south-west */
    u[8] =   u_x - u_y;  /* south-east */
    /* equilibrium densities */
    /* zero velocity density: weight w0 */
    d_equ[0] = w0 * local_density * (1.0 - u_sq / (2.0 * c_sq));
    /* axis speeds: weight w1 */
    d_equ[1] = w1 * local_density * (1.0 + u[1] / c_sq
                                     + (u[1] * u[1]) / (2.0 * c_sq * c_sq)
                                     - u_sq / (2.0 * c_sq));
    d_equ[2] = w1 * local_density * (1.0 + u[2] / c_sq
                                     + (u[2] * u[2]) / (2.0 * c_sq * c_sq)
                                     - u_sq / (2.0 * c_sq));
    d_equ[3] = w1 * local_density * (1.0 + u[3] / c_sq
                                     + (u[3] * u[3]) / (2.0 * c_sq * c_sq)
                                     - u_sq / (2.0 * c_sq));
    d_equ[4] = w1 * local_density * (1.0 + u[4] / c_sq
                                     + (u[4] * u[4]) / (2.0 * c_sq * c_sq)
                                     - u_sq / (2.0 * c_sq));
    /* diagonal speeds: weight w2 */
    d_equ[5] = w2 * local_density * (1.0 + u[5] / c_sq
                                     + (u[5] * u[5]) / (2.0 * c_sq * c_sq)
                                     - u_sq / (2.0 * c_sq));
    d_equ[6] = w2 * local_density * (1.0 + u[6] / c_sq
                                     + (u[6] * u[6]) / (2.0 * c_sq * c_sq)
                                     - u_sq / (2.0 * c_sq));
    d_equ[7] = w2 * local_density * (1.0 + u[7] / c_sq
                                     + (u[7] * u[7]) / (2.0 * c_sq * c_sq)
                                     - u_sq / (2.0 * c_sq));
    d_equ[8] = w2 * local_density * (1.0 + u[8] / c_sq
                                     + (u[8] * u[8]) / (2.0 * c_sq * c_sq)
                                     - u_sq / (2.0 * c_sq));
    /* relaxation step */
    for(kk=0;kk<NSPEEDS;kk++) {
      cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[kk] = (tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[kk]
                                             + params.omega *
                                             (d_equ[kk] - tmp_cells[ii*params.nx + jj].speeds[kk]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

params.nx =300 & params.ny = 200 for a 300x200 d2q9 LB cube...The pragma statement I commented only leads to reduction in increase & also throws Reynolds number out of order... I tried merging the 2 for loops to avoid possible false sharing by making it look like this:

```
c=params.nx*params.ny;
#pragma omp for private (ii,jj,kk,d_equ) shared (cells, tmp_cells)
for(ii=0;ii<c;ii++) {
  /* don't consider occupied cells */
   if(obstacles[ii]) {
    /* called after propagate, so taking values from scratch space
    ** mirroring, and writing into main grid */
    cells[ii].speeds[1] = tmp_cells[ii].speeds[3];
    cells[ii].speeds[2] = tmp_cells[ii].speeds[4];
    ......
    ....
  }
```

The pragma still wouldn't help me speed it up.. I am getting right results here though.. I have been working on this since last Saturday and have not ended up anywhere I fee.. Didn't find much helpful resources online.. I would really appreciate help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my wild guess:

- Your #pragma decaration is probably missing the parallel keyword, thus preventing the loop from being parallelized.
- Most of the variables you declare at the beginning of your code are not defined    as private, hence they are implicitly defined as shared. This makes them susceptible to race  conditions in the first case (but not in the second, since your code runs sequentially). You should either define them as private or (even better) declare them inside the for loop, thus making them private:

```
for(i = 0; i < params.nx * params.ny ; i++) {
    double u[NSPEEDS];
    double d_equ[NSPEEDS];
    ...
    int kk;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandros.. not making variables private was indeed a problem.. I was including the #pragma for statement inside another #pragma omp parallel structure...